# Fwrite save a null file

Tags: php

I have a code in which should open an existing text file into my server, save the text into a variable, then filter the text contained within this variable and save again, as you can see below:

**Text File:**

> Descrição: lorem impsum is a dollar do dolla do dolla style user humam

**Source Code:**

```
$filename = "prods/".$value;
$handle = fopen($filename, "w+");
$contents = fread($handle, filesize($filename));
$newcontent .= str_replace("Descrição:", "Descricao:", $contents);
fwrite($handle,$newcontent);
fclose($handle);
```

The problem is the command write is saving the file again with null text inside him, how can I solve this?

Comment: did you try to echo the output of str_replace? conform $contents have Descrico! then file permissions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to http://php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php:

> 'w+'   Open for reading and writing; place the file pointer at the beginning of the file and truncate the file to zero length. If the file does not exist, attempt to create it.

You are therefore reading an empty string, and writing such a string back too.

The simplest way to solve your problem might be:

```
$filename = "prods/".$value;
$contents = file_get_contents($filename);
$newcontent .= str_replace("Descrição:", "Descricao:", $contents);
file_put_contents($filename, $newcontent);
```

Comment: And the file continue to show Descrição instead of Descricao.

Comment: that's another problem then. What's the encoding of your text file, and the encoding of your PHP file ?

Comment: Well I use notepad++, and I create my php file with charset ISO-8859-1, and the text file is created in windows 7, I can see the encoding the text file, but If I try to save this text in another location the encoding showing is ANSI

Comment: Also, I suppose the `$newcontent` variable has been initialized before. Because it is an error to concatenate to a non-existing variable.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is the mode `'w+'` you use for fopen.

I think `a+` is the one you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

`w+` mode truncates the file to 0 length. You want to use `c+` or `file_get_contents()`, then `file_put_contents()` instead.